# Get userinput from edittext on a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I  wanna start out by saying that im just starting to learn android development(and programming) just so you guys know that im not an expert or anything.

So im creating an app that has 5 fragments. the first one has a spinner, the next 3 have each of them 1 edittext, and the last one has a textview. My problem is, i want to collect the user input from the edittext's and the spinner and use it on a formula that is going to give a result to be shown on the last fragment.

And what i need to know is how do i get the user input from the edittexts and the spinner so i can use them on the formula. 
For you guys to have an idea of what im aiming for here is a video that i found: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcap7DUgIHg
(I have done other apps that use a basic layout with the edittexts all on one activity, but i wanted to try with the type of layout you see on the video)
I want my app to work exactly like that one, but instead of using numberpickers i use edittexts and a spinner.

This is probably a lot for anyone to explain, but i have been on this forever and i need to deliver this school project tomorrow. Hopefully anyone can give me a help with this as fast as possible.

I appreciate any help given!

Thank you

Here is the code:

MainActivity- http://snipt.org/BGaf2

ResultFragment- http://snipt.org/BGag2

One of the Fragments(Basically all the same)- http://snipt.org/BGah5

PS: SORRY FOR ALL THE COMMENTED CODE AND THE LONG POST, I COULDNT PUT MORE THEN 2 LINKS BECAUSE OF MY REPUTATION

EDIT: Thanks for the reputation! I can now post more than 2 links

Comment: Here is a guide on communicationg between fragments http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html